# Write Printed Cells To File

Tags: export, notebooks

Is there a way to write printed out cells to a file easily?

```
NotebookFind[nb = EvaluationNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle];
```

This selects them but I would like to then write to a file.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to write them to a file when they're printed rather than after the fact? This would make it a lot easier, I think

Comment: So for example, instead of `Do[Print[x^2];, {x, 1, 10}]`, something like `Do[Print[x^2]; Write[file, x^2];, {x, 1, 10}]`, which will print AND be writing the content to `file` as well. I don't know the scope of your project, but this could be easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach does not write the selected cells directly to a file, rather it pastes them in a new notebook which is then saved as a file. (So this is not a clean method.) The notebook is created before the procedure and automatically closed without saving once finished.

```
temp = CreateDocument[{}, WindowSelected -> False]; 

NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle];
FrontEndExecute[{
    FrontEndToken["Copy"], FrontEndToken[temp, "Paste"], 
    FrontEndToken[temp, "Save", {"C:/Users/Xavier/Desktop/file.txt", "Text"}]
}];

NotebookClose[temp];
```